# Search of an array is not returning expected result - it keeps coming out false

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, searchbar, zipcode

**Goal**: I am attempting to make a simple search bar that searches for a zip code in the input field and matches it to a zip code in the array. The goal is to create a function that identifies if the zip code exists in the array. If it does it will return a statement if not it will return a different a statement.

**Expected Result**:

1. If a zip code entered in the search bar matches a zip code in the array it will say the area is serviced.
2. If a zip code entered in the search bar does not exist in the array it will say the area is not serviced.
3. If the user tries to submit a blank input field it will say to enter a zip code.

**Actual Result**:

1. If a zip code entered in the search bar matches a zip code in the array it will **say the area is *not* serviced.**
2. If a zip code entered in the search bar does not exist in the array it will say the area is not serviced.
3. If a blank input field is submitted it will say to enter a zip code.

**My Code**:

```js
var zip = ["19505", "19506", "19507", "19508", "19510", "19511", "19512", "19518","19519", "19522", "19523", "19526", "18056", "19529", "19530", "19533", "19534", "19535", "19536", "19538", "19539", "19540", "19541", "19542", "19543", "19544", "19545", "19547", "19611", "19601", "19602", "19604", "19605", "19606", "19607", "19608", "19550", "19551", "19554", "19555","19559","19560","19562", "19564", "19565","19609", "19567", "19610"];

function validateSearchbox(){ 
    var input = document.getElementById("search-box")
    if(input.value.length > 0){ 
        searchResult();
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "Please enter a zip code"; 
    }
};


function searchResult(){ 
    var search = document.getElementById("search-box").value; 
    var index = zip.indexOf("search"); 

    if(index !== -1){ 
        document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "Yes, we do service your area!";
    } else {
            document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "Sorry, we do not service your area!";
        }
};
```

```html
<div id="search"> 
  <input type ="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Zip Code" maxlength="5"/> 
  <button onClick="validateSearchbox();" id="search-btn"> Search </button> 
</div>

<p id="search-result" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 500px;"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to find the index of the string `"search"` instead of the variable `search`. The following works:

```js
function searchResult(){ 
  var search = document.getElementById("search-box").value; 
  var index = zip.indexOf(search); // <--- variable instead of string

  if (index !== -1){ 
    document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "Yes, we do service your area!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "Sorry, we do not service your area!";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unexpected output is caused by using `indexOf` with the string `"search"` instead of the variable `search` declared on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

You passed "search" as string in var index = zip.indexOf("search"); You have to pass search as variable like this.

````
    var search = document.getElementById("search-box").value; 
    var index = zip.indexOf(search); 

    if(index !== -1){ 
        document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "Yes, we do service your area!";
    } else {
            document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML = "Sorry, we do not service your area!";
        }
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires change at this line:
With this, the code will search for the required zip and not the hardcoded zip "search".

`var index = zip.indexOf(search);`

With the below code, its trying to search for string "search" and giving the index= -1 as string "search" is not present in the Zip array.

`var index = zip.indexOf("search");`